# Saiku/Hitachi-Pentaho Schema Workbench

Tags: jdbc, pentaho, olap, saiku, kylin

I'm using the Schema Workbench that I compiled from the source available on [github](https://github.com/pentaho/mondrian) using:

```
 mvn  -Pworkbench package
```

It starts with no problem and there is a folder called drivers which suggests to copy there all the additional JDBC drivers. I did it and restarted the workbench.

The jar I copied is **kylin-jdbc-2.6.1.jar**

The problem is that when I click on Options -> Connection...

[image]

There is no Kylin driver to select. Did anyone get the Schema Workbench working with Kylin and defined a working schema?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

Connection type : Generic database

Custom connection URL: jdbc:kylin://192.168.127.100:7070/project_name_on_kylin

Custom driver class: org.apache.kylin.jdbc.Driver

User name : ADMIN

Password: KYLIN